# C# infinite rows reading

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

As mentioned in title, I'm basically developing a program (Server/client)
where the server inserts some data in a table row, and the client is reading the data.

```
while (true)
{
 string Command = ReadData();
 //Read row
  if (Command != string.Empty)
   {
      switch(Command)
        {
         case "Connection":
         Console.writeLine("Connected !");
         break;
        } 
   }
   else
   {
    console.writeLine("No data were found ! ");
   }
}
```

The `Readata();`function only returns a string if found in a row.

The default Data in that Row is `Null` - there is no stored data in that row until the server inserts some information like a Command on it.

The Client will always read that row and for each time it finds something other than null it will execute some code.

Won't that break the program while executed?

I hope my question is clear, and have a nice day!

Comment: No, I think your question is unclear. I suggest that you add some code to explain better your context.

Comment: Hello ! I'am sorry for disturbing I'll edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't break the program if the client appropriately handles the case where the row doesn't exist.

For example (pseudo code)

```
loop {
   checkForRow();
   if (row.exists) {
      readRowData();
      clearRowData();
   }
}
```

Comment: So i  have to handle the multiple cases of reading a row ! , Thank you very much sir  !

Comment: Yes.  If you're using ADO then you can use something like a DataReader and check the `HasRows` property to see if you read anything from the table.  If `HasRows==true` then you can act on the data.

Comment: Yes ! there will be too much queries or Stored procedures going on cause there will be too much Servers and too much clients won't that overload the program or the database by itself ?

Comment: If you code the handling of the different scenarios properly it won't overload the program.  From the server side, at this point you need to make sure you're planning for a server with enough resources to handle the load you expect.  Without spec on your server environment the question cannot be answered.  If you expect the backend system to be overloaded you will definitely want to make sure you handle timeout exceptions in your program.